# How to structure factories, namespaces, and classes with an autoloader in PHP 5.3?

Tags: php, oop, namespaces, factory

Sorry for the lengthy explanation... I like to be thorough.

I am very new to OOP PHP (about a week of coding in it so far) but I have caught on pretty well and I really like it!  I had placed all of my classes into one GIANT include file and I was including it in every page that needed an object that was being stored in the `SESSION`.  Then today I realized that this was difficult to navigate and that every page was loading every class even if it didn't use it so when I read somewhere that it was best to break classes out into their own files I put all of them in their own files inside a lib folder.

The student class went in the student.php file.
the staff class went into the staff.php file.
etc. etc.

Here is where I get confused... I programed a few factories for looking up certain information from a database.  These factories work great!  I pass the type (such as ID, username, asset) and the factory returns the appropriate lookup which then can be passed the criteria.

Here is an example of what I did for one factory.  The file name is devicelookup.php

```
<?php
// Device Lookup

/*
 *  device lookup interface.  This ensures that each lookup provider has the same function
 */
interface deviceLookupProvider {
    public function lookupDevice($arg);
}

/*
 *  class assetLookupDevice
 */
class assetLookupDevice implements deviceLookupProvider {
    public function lookupDevice($arg) {
        global $mysqli;
        $asset = $mysqli->real_escape_string($arg);
        $sql = "SELECT computer.* FROM `computer` WHERE computer.assetTag = '" . $asset . "' LIMIT 1;";
        $result = $mysqli->query($sql) or die($mysqli->error);
        if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
            return $result->fetch_assoc();
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }
}

/*
 *  device lookup factory.  This returns a lookup object based off the type.
 */
class DeviceLookupFactory {
    public static function createDeviceLookup($type) {
        switch ($type) {
            case "asset":
                return new assetLookupDevice;
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

I am trying to implement the spl_autoloader using code on php.net like so:

```
function my_autoloader($class) {
    include 'lib/' . $class . '.php';
}

spl_autoload_register('my_autoloader');
```

This kind of function would work great for student, staff, workflow and the other classes that are the same name as their files but I feel strange about breaking apart the factory and it's implementations into their own files within /lib.

If I have to do this kind of break apart then I want them grouped into their own folders or something and then I ran into namespaces.  I sort of understand the concept of putting a namespace on an individual class... but I don't.

And, if I figure out the best structure for namespacing then I should be able to call

```
<?php
spl_autoload_extensions(".php"); // comma-separated list
spl_autoload_register();
?>
```

to just magically include all the class files that are needed as they are needed.

So... how does one structure this environment?  I want to structure everything properly so I can reuse the object coding for the larger application that isn't OOP in the future.

Comment: first things first, if you're using autoloaders, you really need to have each class and interface separated into its own file. Unlike other languages, PHP is okay with files that have multiple classes, but it really complicates things for autoloading.

Comment: Doing that now then! I have read that autoloaders do not like camelcase e.g. "assignmentLookupProvider".  Should I leave the class named like this and just make the file lowercase?  TY!

Comment: the default autoloader assumes all filenames will be lower case, regardless of the case of the class itself. If you write your own autoloader, you can make your own decisions on that.

Comment: I read here: [link](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.spl-autoload-register.php#92514) that the autloader is faster (i'll admit barely) but I think this is the way I want to do it.  I finished creating a file named after each class and implementation I have.  Now I have 19 files in the root of the /lib folder.  I suppose the next step is to understand namespacing so I can place a Lookup Folder and by the end of it have a structure maybe like this?:
/lib/core/assignment.php
/lib/core/student.php
/lib/core/lookup/student/studentlookupfactory.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IMO, you should conform to the PSR-0 ([see the full spec](https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/blob/master/accepted/PSR-0.md)) when it comes to class naming and file hierarchy. Then you can use a PSR-0 compliant autoloader and [avoid writing your own](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/class_loader.html).

At the very least, every class, interface, trait should be in its own file named exactly the same as the class/interface/trait name.

Comment: I found that earlier too and I guess I didn't understand still.  If I am making this for an inhouse application what should the vendor name be?  Where should the autoload function exist and do I need to change that function to automatically look in lib/ first?  by default it looks in the root of my application since I put it in the include file located at the root.  Sorry for my ignorance on this matter.

Comment: OK! I think I am getting the hang of this.  I made a folder called core and I placed JsonHandler.php (with capitals) into that folder.  I set it's namespace to "core".  Now when I declare the JsonHandler object class I do new core\JsonHandler!  And this is how I can group my lookups and main classes and have them just work.  Thank you all for the help!  But, If anyone wants to continue adding information it never hurts.